# match two open brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

so let's say i have this

```
example: 1
[
   this shouldn't be matched
]
example : 2 
[
   some bla
   [
      other bla
   ]

]
```

i watch to check if the file has any nested brackets . i dont want to actually check if brackets match i only need to see if they exist .

now in my head this sound simple , but i couldnt get nay thing out of this (in terms of regular expressions )

so i came up with something ( a scanner hopefully ) which is just a simple javascrpit function .

```
function idNested(str){
    // match all brackets
    var g = str.match(/[\[\]]/g);
    // join them into one string
    var b = g.join('');
    // match double bracket if there is any , it means that there is nesting :)
    return b.match(/\[\[/) ? true : false;
}
```

the first regular expression gets all the brackets . and then i join them into one big string and search for two brackets that follow each other .

so my question is really based of two things .

1 - Is there a regular expression that would just solve my problem ?!

2- Does this function has any downfalls ? if so then please suggest something else .

Comment: and here is mine /\\[[^\\]*?\\[/g

Comment: It doesn't make sense because you can't see if they exist if you don't want to match brackets. Otherwise, thier random existence could be `^(?=.*\[.*\[)(?=.*\].*\])`

Comment: I was going to answer, but @dandavis already offered the solution (find a second open bracket before the first one is closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering number 2:**

No, this shouldn't have any downfalls if your brackets are nested correctly.

Essentially you are reducing a string down to only its brackets. In your case, the string would become `[][[]]`.

Assume we are processing the string 2 characters at a time. There are only 4 possible combinations:

1. `[[` we found a nested bracket, and we are done with matching, since the rest of the string must have closing brackets for these (e.g. `[[]]`).
2. `[]` we found a single set of brackets, ignore this result, and move on.
3. `][` this can never happen because it implies that we either have already matched **1** (e.g. `[[][...`) and we are done with algorithm, or you have invalid bracket nesting (e.g. `[]][`).
4. `]]` we would have already found **1** if brackets are nested correctly, and thus would never reach this state.

Thus your algorithm would work.

**Answering number 1:**

Having said that, the code would be much simpler with a single regular expression (assuming proper nesting):

```
str.match(/\[[^\]]*\[/)
```

Strings that would be matched:

- `[[]]`
- `[[[]]]`
- `[][[]]`

Strings that wouldn't be matched:

- `[][]`
- `[]`

Strings we don't care about (since they aren't properly nested):

- `[[`
- `][[`
- `[[[]]`

Comment: The question is about nesting, assumptions are irrelavent. Might as well match two opening brackets `\[.*\[`. Its the same thing.

Comment: @sln: That regex would match `[][]` while the one I posted wouldn't. You might say that mine will fail with `[[`, but according to OP, that string would never exist. On the other hand, `[][]` is a string that would exist (since the brackets are nested correctly). Thus we need a regex that would match `[[]]`, but wouldn't match `[][]`, for example. `[[` is irrelevant, since it would never be passed to this regex.

Answer (score 2):

Why not check for this:

```
\[              # Match an open bracket
[^\]]*?         # Match zero or more non-closing bracket ] lazily
\[              # Match another opening bracket
[^\]]*          # Match zero or more non-closing bracket ] greedily
\]              # Match a closing bracket.
```

It works like this, if we matched an open brack `[`, then we look for another opening-bracket `[`, and we make sure that we don't cross a closing bracket `]`.

If the above expression matches then there is nesting in the text.

```
var isNested = '[f daflkd [hfds ] fdaf d[ [] fd'.match(/\[[^\]]*?\[[^\]]*\]/g);
```

**NOTE:** This assumes the file doesn't contain impropriety nested brackets.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xV3cJ3)

Comment: Not really, `[[` is not nested brackets.

Comment: @sln Thank you for pointing that out, can you comment on the updated solution.

Comment: I think you're on right track, maybe the only way to know is to get the two sets `\[.*?\[.*?\].*?\]`

Comment: @sln Thank you. I guess you are right, nevertheless I am gonna leave it as is for now.